Problems with the sf::Sprite class
I am making a game with SFML 3 which removed the default constructor for sf::Sprite.
I have this Player class:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Player
{
public:

    Player();

    sf::Vector2f GetPos() const;
    sf::Vector2u GetSize() const;
    sf::Sprite GetSprite() const;
    float GetSpeed() const;
    float GetMass() const;
    bool GetAlive() const;

    void SetPos(sf::Vector2f pos);
    bool SetSprite(const char* filePath);
    void SetMass(float mass);
    
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    void Die();

private:
    sf::Vector2f Pos;
    sf::Texture Texture;
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    float Speed;
    float Mass;
    bool Alive;
    
};

and this constructor
Player::Player()
{
    Pos = { 400, 400 };
    Texture.loadFromFile("assets/images/Player.png");
    Sprite.setTexture(Texture);
    Mass = 10.f;
    Speed = 5;
    Alive = true;

}

obviously it gives me an error that says:

no default constructor exists for class "sf::Sprite"

I tried putting the Sprite and Texture variables in the main function and it worked, I tried creating a Sprite variable inside the constructor and it worked but then the GetSprite and SetSprite function didn't have a variable to get or set, and I want to have all the variables related to the player in the Player class.
Please let me know what i could do to fix it

This question is similar to: Why should I prefer to use member initializer lists?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

please don't store textures directly and use shared_ptr<sf::Texture> instead to get around the white square problem which you are about to run into once your code compiles

@AhmedAEK Good point. I think a std::unique_ptr would be sufficient in most situations though since it enables move semantics and preferable since it's cheaper and makes the ownership clear.

In SFML3, you pass the texture to the Sprite constructor using the member initializer list:
Player::Player() :
    Texture("assets/images/Player.png"),
    Sprite(Texture)
{
    // ...
}

